# AngularJS Controller Display error

Tags: angularjs-scope

I am new to AngularJS and stuck with an output.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<html ng-app>  
<body>  
<div class="container" data-ng-controller="simpleController">  
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | orderBy:'name'">
        {{ cust.name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.city | lowercase }} - {{                   cust.balc | currency }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>  
<script>
    angular.module("app",[]).controller("simpleController",function($scope){  
        $scope.customers = [  
                           { name: 'Dave', city: 'Jaipur', balc: '500'},  
                           { name: 'Shruti', city: 'Toronto', balc: '1000'},  
                           { name: 'Rishu', city: 'Phoenix', balc: '2000'},  
                           { name: 'Shweta', city: 'California',balc:'3000'}
                           ];  
    }  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code.
I have put single quotes before div tag and li tag because it wasnt displaying on stackoverflow otherwise.

Comment: Can you place a JSFiddle Link?

Comment: how do we do that?

Answer (score 0):

In ng-app you are not passing the module name.
Please Find The JSFiddle Link I have Updated It with code.

```
HTML Code
<html ng-app="app">

  <body>
    <div class="container" data-ng-controller="simpleController">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | orderBy:'name'">
          {{ cust.name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.city | lowercase }} - {{ cust.balc | currency }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>

JS Code
angular.module("app", []).controller("simpleController", function($scope) {
  $scope.customers = [{
    name: 'Dave',
    city: 'Jaipur',
    balc: '500'
  }, {
    name: 'Shruti',
    city: 'Toronto',
    balc: '1000'
  }, {
    name: 'Rishu',
    city: 'Phoenix',
    balc: '2000'
  }, {
    name: 'Shweta',
    city: 'California',
    balc: '3000'
  }];
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rs64h0jz/

Comment: I think that is not necessary. I am passing the controller name in ng-controller.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is right, but I guess you want to use them in ng-repeat, so you can use whatever name you want in the expressions, this name will be the current element of your array. You have to wrap it like this:

```
`<div ng-repeat="cust in customers">{{ cust.name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.city | lowercase }} - {{ cust.balc | currency }}</div>`
```

Comment: Actually, you can use it the way you wrote it but: 1. You hadn't closed the controller function on the line before the closing `</script>` tag and after the `}`. You should add `);`. 2. And you should add a value to the `<html ng-app> ` like so `<html ng-app='app'> `

Comment: okk.. your code worked on my system. Apart from the other problems, it wasnt working because I hadn't add **['$scope'**, function($scope)

Comment: That was my suggestion in the fiddle.Because -> from Angular documentation: _Controllers are "classes" or "constructor functions" that are responsible for providing the application behavior that supports the declarative markup in the template. The recommended way of declaring Controllers is using the array notation:_ . You can read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller